# Is there something wrong with the logic in my remove function?

Tags: python, pyqt5

My issue is that although I can get the program running correctly the first time, I am unable to edit my userList after I press the roll button.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QHBoxLayout, QCompleter,
                             QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import random
import sys


# create widget that will add and remove characters from the roulette pool
class AddRemoveWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, userList):
        super(AddRemoveWidget, self).__init__()

        self.name = name
        # create a separate list as out roulette pool
        self.userList = userList
        self.added = False

        # set up add and remove buttons
        self.label = QLabel(self.name)
        self.button_removed = QPushButton("Remove")
        self.button_add = QPushButton("Add")

        # set up the "box" for interaction
        self.hBox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.button_removed)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.button_add)

        # attribute functions to each button
        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.button_removed.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        self.setLayout(self.hBox)

        self.update_button_state()

    def show(self):
        for w in [self, self.label, self.button_add, self.button_removed]:
            w.setVisible(True)

    def hide(self):
        for w in [self, self.label, self.button_add, self.button_removed]:
            w.setVisible(False)

    def add(self, name):
        self.added = True
        self.userList.append(self.name)
        self.update_button_state()
        #return self.userList

    def remove(self, name):
        self.added = False
        self.update_button_state()
        self.userList.remove(self.name)
        #return self.userList

    def update_button_state(self):
        if self.added == True:
            self.button_add.setStyleSheet("background-color: #32CD32; color #fff;")
            self.button_removed.setStyleSheet("background-color: none; color: none;")
        else:
            self.button_add.setStyleSheet("background-color: none; color: none;")
            self.button_removed.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D32F2f; color: #fff")


# create main window (think of this as the main())
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def addCharToList(self, character):
        self.charList.append(character)

    def initUI(self):
        self.controls = QWidget()
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.userList = []

        # list of elements
        charactersAll = # assume generic stuff
        

        self.widgets = []

        for name in charactersAll:
            item = AddRemoveWidget(name, self.userList)
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controlsLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.controls.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Rolling")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1024, 680)

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("<h1>Roulette</h1>")
        self.label1.adjustSize()
        self.label1.move(10, 15)

        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Add Characters to Roulette")
        self.label2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Comic_Sans', 15))
        self.label2.move(10, 55)
        self.label2.adjustSize()

        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label3.setText("<h1>Team 1:</h1>")
        self.label3.adjustSize()
        self.label3.move(540, 30)

        self.label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label4.setText("")
        self.label4.move(540, 70)

        self.label5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label5.setText("")
        self.label5.move(540, 85)

        self.label6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label6.setText("")
        self.label6.move(540, 100)

        self.label7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label7.setText("<h1>Team 2:</h1>")
        self.label7.adjustSize()
        self.label7.move(540, 120)

        self.label8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label8.setText("")
        self.label8.move(540, 145)

        self.label9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label9.setText("")
        self.label9.move(540, 160)

        self.label10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label10.setText("")
        self.label10.move(540, 175)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)

        self.searchBar = QLineEdit()
        self.searchBar.adjustSize()
        self.searchBar.textChanged.connect(self.updateDisplay)

        self.completer = QCompleter(charactersAll)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.searchBar.setCompleter(self.completer)

        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.searchBar)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        containerLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 85, 0, 0)

        container.setLayout(containerLayout)
        container.setFixedSize(400, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Roll")
        self.b1.setGeometry(10, 610, 390, 40)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.RandRoll)

    def updateDisplay(self, text):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            if text.lower() in widget.name.lower():
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()

    def updateText(self):
        self.label4.adjustSize()
        self.label6.adjustSize()

    def RandRoll(self):

        #create a separate list to save "names" for rerolls
        self.tempList = []

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label4.setText(selectedString + ", ")
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label5.setText(selectedString + ", ")
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label6.setText(selectedString)
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label8.setText(selectedString + ", ")
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label9.setText(selectedString + ", ")
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        selectedString = random.choice(self.userList)
        self.tempList.append(selectedString)
        self.label10.setText(selectedString)
        self.userList.remove(selectedString)

        # add back all "removed" names into userList
        self.userList = self.userList + self.tempList

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
```

I'm thinking it is a problem with my add and remove functions under the AddRemoveWidget but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually various problems, but the main issue is that you're accessing (and, most importantly, *modifying*) the same list from objects that should *not* do it.

This happens here:

```
        # create a separate list as out roulette pool
        self.userList = userList
```

You are **not** creating a separate list, you're just setting the same list as an instance attribute, but the object is shared amongst the main window instance and all `AddRemoveWidget` widgets.

Instead of adding and removing items from the `AddRemoveWidget`, just connect its buttons to the main class and let that manage the contents of the list.

```
class AddRemoveWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(AddRemoveWidget, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.added = False
        # ...

    def add(self, name):
        self.added = True
        self.update_button_state()

    def remove(self, name):
        self.added = False
        self.update_button_state()

    # ...


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        for name in charactersAll:
            item = AddRemoveWidget(name)
            item.button_add.clicked.connect(lambda _, name=name: self.addName(name))
            item.button_removed.clicked.connect(lambda _, name=name: self.removeName(name))
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)
        # ...

    def addName(self, name):
        if not name in self.userList:
            self.userList.append(name)

    def removeName(self, name):
        if name in self.userList:
            self.userList.remove(name)
```

Note that I used a lambda in order to send the name parameter to the functions, but I set that parameter as a keyword *after* a `_` argument. This is because `clicked` *always* sends a `checked` parameter when emitted (and you're not interested in that) and the name argument must be set within the scope of the lambda (otherwise it will always be the last value in the for cycle). Do some research about lambda scope in for/while loops to know more.

Also note that I didn't add the `RandRoll` function, as I've not really understood what you're going to do there, but consider that it has an important issue: since you're always removing items from the list, you'll probably end up in having an empty list, which will cause a crash in for `choice`, as it raises an exception if the argument is an empty sequence.

Finally, remove both the `show()` and `hide()` implementations, as they are unnecessary (and potentially wrong).

Comment: Thank you so much! If you're at all curious, i set up my RandRoll to display results of the roll. I would remove them from the list in order to prevent repetition, but i would put them into a temp list and add the list back into the main one at the end. It's extremely messy but I'm hoping that I can clean things up as I work on this. most probably I can just do a for loop into a if statement and check if the name exists in the temp. 

All in all, thank you!